# Applescript to run at shut down

Tags: applescript, shutdown

I am trying to make an application using AppleScript which can remind to check my mails, if I forget to check, at shutdown.

I took help from this link: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1375949&tstart=0&messageID=7088687#7088687

In this link they have suggested that I can run a quite application which can be started at login and when I will try to shut down, system will try to close it and desired result will be obtained!

I have tried this script code:

```
say "Good morning Miraaj! I will be reminding you to check your mails at shutdown. Have a rocking day!!"
```

on quit

```
set the alert_message to "Have you checked your mails?"
display dialog the alert_message buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 1
set the my_choice to the button returned of the result
if my_choice is "Yes" then
    tell application "Finder"
        shut down
    end tell
else
    tell application "Safari"
        open location "www.gmail.com"
    end tell
end if
continue quit
```

end quit

but it is not working for me!

Can anyone suggest where I may be wrong ??

thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: I think you might actually get more help on SuperUser.com simply because its ActionScript.

Comment: Miraaj, did you ask this on SuperUser? I checked and didn't find anything. I'm wondering about something similar: triggering an applescript when an external monitor is connected/disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working now when I saved it as stay open application! :)